# Ayuda con llenar vector con sus posiciones aleatorias java

Tags: java

Tengo ese método pero necesito que el vector no se llene en orden,quiero, que por ejemplo en la posición 7 sea el primer objeto, luego en la 1, así sucesivamente.

Con el aleatorio que tengo funciona, pero no me sirve porque si genera una posición que ya está ocupada y todavía hay al menos una posición vacía en el vector necesito que entre en la posición vacía.

```
public synchronized void entrarCoche(Carro nuevo) {
        int a = Numeroaleatorio(0, 7);

        System.out.println("El numero aleatorio de entrada es " + a);

        for (int i = 0; i < carro.length; i++) {
            int b = Numeroaleatorio(1, 100);
            Carro x = new Carro(b);
            if (carro[a] == null) {
                carro[a] = x;
                System.out.println("Entró carro en la posicion" +a +"--"+ carro[a]);


            } else {
                System.out.println(i + "NO ENTRO EN LA POSICION " + carro[i]);
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Hola Andres, si quieres llenar un array con posiciones aleatorias, te sugiero generar este array con posiciones aleatorias únicas y llenarlo con objetos Carro. De esta forma incluso no tendrías que buscar por posiciones "Vacías".

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero crear un array con números aleatorios únicos los cuales no se repetirán  e iterar sobre este array.

Crea un método para generar un array de números aleatorios que no se repitan:

```
public int[] Numeroaleatorios(int min, int max){    
    Random r = new Random();        
    int[] randomNumbers = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(min, max).distinct().limit(max).toArray(); 
    return  randomNumbers;
}
```

ahora el método `entrarCoche()` obtendrá este array de numeros aleatorios en insertara los objetos Carro.

En este ejemplo se define como dimension del array 10 (indices de 0 a 9):

```
  private  Carro[] carro;


    public synchronized void entrarCoche() {

            carro = new Carro[10]; //10 objetos carro

            int[] numerosAleatorios =  Numeroaleatorios(0,10); //10 numeros aleatorios (0 a 9)
            for (int i = 0; i < numerosAleatorios.length; i++) {
            Carro x = new Carro();                       
            carro[numerosAleatorios[i]] = x; 
            System.out.println("Entró carro en la posición: " + numerosAleatorios[i]);

    }
```

tendrías una salida por ejemplo:

```
Entró carro en la posición: 5
Entró carro en la posición: 3
Entró carro en la posición: 0
Entró carro en la posición: 2
Entró carro en la posición: 4
Entró carro en la posición: 6
Entró carro en la posición: 9
Entró carro en la posición: 1
Entró carro en la posición: 8
Entró carro en la posición: 7
```

Comment: Funciona pero el trabajo es con hilos, a la vez que los carros van entrando, se van yendo, es decir que si genera un numero aleatorio, despues puede que esa posicion esté vacia porque ya no está el carro

Comment: Mi objetivo es estar revisando cuales posiciones están vacias, para asi mismo ir metiendo carros, el ejercicio es un parking con hilos, con carros que entran y salen

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que a tu arreglo `Carro[] carro` debes llenar con carros en posiciones aleatorias ¿cierto?. Me marea un poco que ese método tenga un parámetro. Ese arreglo ya existe antes de invocarse a ese método, y tiene una cantidad delimitada. ¿Estoy en lo correcto? Y en el constructor de la clase `Carro` indica la posición donde estará (algo así como su lugar de aparcamiento).

Mi pregunta es: ¿pueden haber más carros que los valores permitidos por tu número aleatorio?. Es decir,si tienes 200 carros, y llamas a tu método `Numeroaleatorio(1,100)` ¿qué pasará con los otros 100 que no entren?

Comment: Exacto, trato de asimilar un parqueadero, parking o estacionamiento. El arreglo es el parking, y los carros los que lo van a ocupar. el objetivo es crear un parqueadero que va a meter y sacar carros, entonces puede que la posición 5 esté llena por 5 segundos y luego quede vacia. entonces necesito estar llenando el arreglo con posiciones aleatorias, hasta que haya al menos un cupo.

Comment: En poca palabras, se tiene que estár consultando las posiciones del arreglo, si están o no llenas, pdsta: el trabajo es con hilos